# iOS 7 App gets Low Memory Warnings in Instruments

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, instruments

I used Instruments to check my memory managment because I saw that my memory raises & raises until I get a memory warning. It drops some MB after that but the next warning is just 1min away. I even expected that it drops alot more memory if I popToViewController but it stays at an avarage of 30MB. Is there something significant in the allocation summary? I'm very new to this analysing stuff.
Any tips & tricks are welcome!

[image: Instruments Allocations]

Drawing a Percentage Circle into a UIImageView:

```
- (UIImageView *)applyCircleWithPersentage:(int)persent andTintColor:(UIColor *)color; {

  // begins image context with the size of the imageView and the scale of the actual device (retina, non retina)
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
  // creates a graphics context
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  // sets the distance of the circle to the cell frame in pixels
  CGFloat arcPadding = 8;
  // creates the radius of the circle
  CGFloat arcRadius = (self.frame.size.width / 2) - arcPadding;
  // sets the center of the circle
  CGPoint arcCenter = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2);

  // the first cicle is always displayed 100% and gets overdrawn by the second circle with the real percentage!
  // sets the degree for the first circle
  CGFloat startAngle = radians(0);
  CGFloat endAngle = radians(360);

  // creates the path of the first circle in counter clockwise (the last value is "0")
  CGContextAddArc(context, arcCenter.x, arcCenter.y, arcRadius, startAngle, endAngle, 0);
  // sets the linewidth of the first circle
  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 6.0f);

  // gets the RGBA-values of the color
  CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;
  [color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
  // sets the RGB-values and lowers the Alpha-value to make the first circle lighter
  [[UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:0.3f] setStroke];
  // draws the first circle
  CGContextStrokePath(context);

  // Same here for the second circle!
  // we use the 270° to start at the top to draw the circle
  startAngle = radians(270);
  // sets the persentage value in degrees
  endAngle = radians(270 - (360 * persent) / 100);

  // adds the circle path in clockwise direction (the last value is "1")
  CGContextAddArc(context, arcCenter.x, arcCenter.y, arcRadius, startAngle, endAngle, 1);
  // sets the linewidth for the second circle
  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 6.0f);
  // sets the full color for the second circle
  [color setStroke];
  // draws the second one
  CGContextStrokePath(context);

  // defines the text in the middle of the circle
  NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%%", persent];
  NSMutableDictionary *atts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
  // to center the text vertical
  NSMutableParagraphStyle* style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
  [style setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
  [atts setObject:color forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
  [atts setObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
  [atts setObject:style forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];
  // sets the text and centers it in horizontal direction
  // the "-1" fixed the text for me to get it really in the middle, but maybe you have to remove it
  [text drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y + ((self.frame.size.height - font.pointSize) / 2) - 1, self.frame.size.height, font.pointSize) withAttributes:atts];

  // creates the image
  UIImage *retImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  // ends the graphics context
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  // sets the image for the imageView
  [self setImage:retImage];
  // and returns the imageView
  return self;
}
```

Comment: Then you need to check the `retainCounts` of your class level variables and the resources you think is still live, `at runtime`. Once you find them out set them to `nil` and see if it makes any difference which i think you will see. Handle `didReceiveMemoeryWarning` delegate and dispose any resource that can be recreated.

Comment: is the value of CG raster data & CoreUI image data normal? or is there any cache from my image manipulations, like bitmaps? I've posted one example above, but as I can remember from the apple doc: if i dont use any CG-create, i dont own them so i dont have to release them... is this right?